# Why scatter.legend_elements is limited in size?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, legend, scatter

I'm trying to plot with this code :

```
import pandas as pd
import random as rd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

datasets = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g','g','g','h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v']
d = {'x': [rd.random()*len(i) for i in datasets]
     , 'y': [rd.random()*len(i) for i in datasets]
     , 'source': datasets} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
fig = plt.figure()
categ = df.source.astype('category')
datasets_legend = dict(enumerate(categ.cat.categories)).values()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
scatter = ax.scatter(df.x, df.y, c=categ.cat.codes, cmap='Set3')
plt.title("test", fontsize=18)
plt.legend(handles=scatter.legend_elements()[0], labels=datasets_legend, title="datasets")
plt.show()
```

But the legend is not showing every line (it is limited to the 9th first elements).
Any idea how can I get the full legend ?

Best regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.PathCollection.legend_elements), you can see there is a `num` option to `scatter.legend_elements()` which controls how many elements should be included in the legend. By default, `num='auto'`, which tries to find a nice number of elements to display.

To show all elements, you can use `num=None`, which should give you labels for all the unique elements in the mappable.

So, use this line of code:

```
plt.legend(handles=scatter.legend_elements(num=None)[0], labels=datasets_legend, title="datasets")
```

Which produces this figure:

[image]

[Docs for the `num` parameter](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.PathCollection.legend_elements), for reference:

> `num`   int, None, "auto" (default), array-like, or `Locator`
>
> Target number of elements to create. If `None`, use all unique elements of the mappable array. If an integer, target to use `num` elements in the normed range. If `"auto"`, try to determine which option better suits the nature of the data. The number of created elements may slightly deviate from `num` due to a `Locator` being used to find useful locations. If a list or array, use exactly those elements for the legend. Finally, a `Locator` can be provided.